# Tensor product over local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

If $R$ is a local ring and $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated R-modules such that $M\otimes N = 0$ then it follows from Nakayama's lemma that either $M=0$ or $N=0$. This I know. But now

> I am looking for an example of a local ring $R$ and two modules $M,N$ such that $M\otimes N = 0$ but neither $M=0$ nor $N=0$.

Thanks

Comment: The page https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593619/is-it-true-that-the-tensor-product-of-any-two-nonzero-r-modules-is-nonzero-if characterizes in Eric Wofsey's answer all the commutative rings $R$ such that the tensor product of two nonzero $R$-modules is always nonzero: $R$ must be a local ring satisfying an extra condition (see #3 in Wofsey's answer), and in the case when the local ring is a *domain*, the extra condition implies $R$ has to be a field.  But Keenan's answer below is certainly a more efficient solution when you're only looking at domains.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be a domain which is not a field. If $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$. Then $K,K/R$ are non-zero $R$-modules satisfying $K\otimes_R(K/R)=0$. In particular, you could take $R$ local and have an example of the type sought.

Comment: @Kennan Kidwell: is $\mathbb{Q} \mathop{\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})}$ really $0$?

Comment: Take $r\in\mathbf{Q}$ and $s\in\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$. Since $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$ is torsion, there is $n\geq 1$ such that $ns=0$. Since $\mathbf{Q}$ is divisible, we can write $r=nr^\prime$ for some $r^\prime\in\mathbf{Q}$. Now $r\otimes s=nr^\prime\otimes s=r^\prime\otimes ns=0$. This idea works generally for a domain $R$ and its quotient field $K$. A divisible $R$-module tensored with a torsion $R$-module is zero.

Comment: @Kennan Kidwell: of course! Thanks.